# How do i get my spyder to stop giving me an error and open

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Spyder will not launch no matter what i try. This is what comes up[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZhGp.png)

I have uninstalled and reinstalled spyder and anaconda multiple times but it has not helped. I have also tried upgrading and downgrading spyder. I have tried lots of solutions found on the internet as well\I did it!

Comment: See this question for a possible solution [Correct Debug Startup error in Spyder 5.0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69638839/correct-debug-startup-error-in-spyder-5-0-5)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please follow the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to reinstall Anaconda. Perhaps that will solve your issue. If not, you can simply use our [Mac app](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases), which shouldn't have this problem.